# Export a CSV files and changing the number of digits after the comma and summing the Verts

Tags: python, csv

I have been using this script which works very well. However, I require two changes to the output file. 1. The numbers are too long. I need five digits after the comma, currently there are ten. 2. Is there a way to sum up the vertices and place the total number on the first line. Examples are provided.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code I am using to get the result.

```
import bpy
import os

name = bpy.context.object.name


outputFile  = bpy.path.abspath("//CSV_Exports\\" + name + ".csv")

print(outputFile)

verts = [ bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ v.co for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices ]

csvLines = [ " ".join([ str(v) for v in co ]) + "\n" for co in verts ]

f = open( outputFile, 'w' )
f.writelines( csvLines )
f.close()
```

Comment: To limit the number of digits after the decimal, you can use string formatting print("%.5f" % 1.23456789). Can you clarify whta yo mean by sum of vertices? How is the sum of two vertices 10+8 = 2? Do you mean count?

Comment: Also, is your CSV delimeter a space?

Comment: sorry, yes of course. The count of the vertices. How would the code look like? My delimeter is a space.

Comment: Is it always going to be a pair of vertices? Or is it possible for the count to differ per column?

Comment: Yes it always differs according to the number of vertices exported in the csv file. It's basically a circle or closed loop in blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. It is a bit messy because we don't know whether a certain row in verts will have a value in the given column.

```
verts = [ bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ v.co for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices ]
csvLines = [ " ".join(["%.5f" % v for v in co ]) + "\n" for co in verts ]

colDict = {}
for i in range(len(verts)):
    for j in range(len(verts[i])):
        if (j in colDict):
            colDict[j] += 1
        else:
            colDict[j] = 1

colList = []
for i in range(len(colDict)):
    colList.append(str(colDict[i]))

data = [" ".join(colList), "\n"] + csvLines

f = open("test.csv", 'w' )
f.writelines(data)
f.close()
```

Also, you might want to look into using an actual csvwriter instead of just writing to file plainly.

I came  up with a slightly better solution if you want to use itertools

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import os

verts = [ bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ v.co for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices ]
csvLines = [ " ".join(["%.5f" % v for v in co ]) + "\n" for co in verts ]

cols = [list(filter(None,i)) for i in zip_longest(*verts)]
colLength = [str(len(x)) for x in cols]
data = [" ".join(colLength), "\n"] + csvLines

f = open("test.csv", 'w' )
f.writelines(data)
f.close()
```